# Istanbul.js in the browser

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, mocha.js, istanbul

`Mocha` and `chai` can be used seamlessy in the browser. You import them with the script tag, import your test script and in the browser you end up having a nice summary of the results.

This also makes it trivial to test libraries that manipulate the dom and hence have to be tested in a browser.

How can I integrate `instabul` in such a workflow? With `QUnit` it was as easy as importing `blanket.js`, but it not supported anymore.

Comment: I know this is old but did you ever figure this out?